# How to extract date from time stamp that has month name in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I need to extract date from a time stamp format such as

> "Aug-02-2017 07:54:31 AM UTC"

I want to extract date in the form **2017-08-02**. How to do it in R? I tried using the "lubridate" package but it is unable to parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the anytime library

```
library(anytime)
anydate("Aug-02-2017 07:54:31 AM UTC")
[1] "2017-08-02"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> s1="Aug-02-2017 07:54:31 AM UTC"
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date


> d1=mdy_hms(s1)
> d1
[1] "2017-08-02 07:54:31 UTC" 
> date(d1)
[1] "2017-08-02"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the base `as.POSIXct` function:

```
> format(as.POSIXct("Aug-02-2017 07:54:31 AM UTC",format='%b-%d-%Y'))
[1] "2017-08-02"
```